# datedif function in libreoffice with mm/dd/yyyy format

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I can't seem to use the datedif function in case my dates are in mm/dd/yyyy and it always returns #NAME as value. I am using datedif(A2,B2,d). If it only works with a certain format is there a way to convert my existing dates to that format?

Comment: Did you try putting the d argument in quotes? In other words, does DATEDIF(A2,B2,"d") work?

Answer (score 0):

As @tohuwawohu [wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52693224/datedif-function-in-libreoffice-with-mm-dd-yyyy-format#comment92319186_52693224).

[Syntax](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/DATEDIF)

```
DATEDIF(Start date; End date; Interval)
```

**Start date** is the date from when the calculation is carried out.

**End date** is the date until the calculation is carried out. End date must be later, than Start date.

**Interval** is a string, accepted values are "d", "m", "y", "ym", "md" or "yd".

```
|Value for "Interval"| Return value                                                                                           |
|--------------------|--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| "d"                | Number of whole days between Start date and End date.                                                  |
| "m"                | Number of whole months between Start date and End date.                                                |
| "y"                | Number of whole years between Start date and End date.                                                 |
| "ym"               | Number of whole months when subtracting years from the difference of Start date and End date.          |
| "md"               | Number of whole days when subtracting years and months from the difference of Start date and End date. |
| "yd"               | Number of whole days when subtracting years from the difference of Start date and End date.            |
```

**Example**

Birthday calculation. A man was born on 1974-04-17. Today is 2012-06-13.

`=DATEDIF("1974-04-17";"2012-06-13";"y")` yields 38. `=DATEDIF("1974-04-17";"2012-06-13";"ym")` yields 1. `=DATEDIF("1974-04-17";"2012-06-13";"md")` yields 27.
 So he is 38 years, 1 month and 27 days old.

`=DATEDIF("1974-04-17";"2012-06-13";"m")` yields 457, he has been living for 457 months.

`=DATEDIF("1974-04-17";"2012-06-13";"d")` yields 13937, he has been living for 13937 days.

`=DATEDIF("1974-04-17";"2012-06-13";"yd")` yields 57, his birthday was 57 days ago.